# How to make a http request in local env with file_get_contents or curl

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have a problem with a very old php 5.3 code in a project that we try to refactorize...

In the code, there is some local link like :

file_get_contents('http://loc.name.xxx/public/api/stations');

When I access via the browser => this link return a json but when it's called from a phpfile => the file_get_contents return nothing...

I've configured my local to accept url_fopen but I still have this error. I've also tried to run the request via curl but without success.

Is there a way to retrieve the Json ? or to make it works ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Can you give your cURL code? Difficult to advise without seeing it. Did you try to set the User Agent string with cURL to the same User Agent string as your browser?